# What is the concept behind writing a cancel operation in c++?

Tags: c++, function, operation, cancellation

(Please note this is my first question so apologies on rule-breaking just let me know and I'll fix it)

I'm attempting to write a cancel operation for a software download application. This application will first transfer the software to the device and then install the software on it. (These are givens I'm not allowed to change).

What should the cancel operation do? When a user presses 'cancel', the application should stop transferring/installing the software immediately.

Question: Since I've never written a "cancel" function, I'm wondering what are the types of things to consider when writing the code, and what are the common bugs I should expect and how to deal with them?

Couldn't find anything in google so if you have some links that would be good reads I'd really appreciate it since I'm not looking for answers I'm just looking for guidelines/macro/concept help

Comment: This is not a bad question per-se, however it is well too broad for Stack Overflow. Here people like questions that can be answered with a  solution, not some general divagations. I.e. a sample code, or a straight answer that explains and solves the problem. You don't even have a well defined problem. I think such more open ended and less technical questions are better received at Programmers Stack Exchange.  I'd try there just for the higher chance of getting an actual good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll go ahead and put it up there as well. Would you suggest I delete the question from here?

Comment: I think it will get put on-hold or moved soon by some moderator. I am not sure why there is no close/hold vote with Migrate to Programmers SE option =). Personally I wouldn't delete it unless it gets some serious -1 votes. If mods don't like it very much, they will do it manually.

Comment: @luk32 thanks for help luk! I posted it there as well

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements, but usually in a cancel operation you will keep a stack of the operations that have been performed so that you can go back and undo them all when cancel is clicked.

Comment: just to clear it up: Keep track of all operations active prior to 'cancel' operation pressed and then make sure they all have the command to STOP when 'cancel' is pressed. (Hopefully I'm repeating what you're saying in different words)